# Pass string variable from Django to Vuejs method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm passing an parameter from Django to a Vue method in my html as such:

```
# Django view
context = {
    'var1': var1,
}
```

```
<!-- html -->
<div>
  <p>Display var1: {{var1}}</p>
  <button @click.prevent="doThis({{var1}})">Do This</button>
</div>

<!-- html result below
Display var1: value_of_var1
-->
```

The above works perfectly however, the `doThis({{var1}})` gives an error.

```
// Vue method
method: {
  doThis(var1){
    console.log(var1)
  }
}
```

I get the following in the console:

```
undefined
...[Vue warn]: Property or method "value_of_var1" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

What am I doing wrong?

How can I get the above error when I'm passing in a variable to the method?

Comment: doThis(var1) - withiut {{}}

Comment: Hey @Estradiaz I'm using {{}} because I'm passing the values from Django - it uses jinja2 templating language. Also, I've set my Vue delimiters to [[ ]]

Comment: Everything worked just fine when the value of var1 was "1". Could the issue be because of the length of the string?

Comment: Ahh ok - `'{{var1}}'` should do, else you try to access varable, but you want to pass string

Comment: Hey @Estradiaz it worked \o/ Thanks. Please post so I can accept

Comment: @alkadelik how did you manage to change delimiters in vuejs3?

Comment: @sebt I wasn't using VueCLI but here's how ```new Vue({ delimiters: ['[[', ']]'], data{}...});```

Comment: @alkadelik ahh that looks like Vue 2 to me. I'm looking for a solution in Vue 3 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first answer above works so I'm leaving it. It is however not optimal for the purpose I wanted. Estradiaz comment is really what I needed. I was missing the quotes `''` in my code. This is required when passing strings into methods. So the solution is:

```
<!-- html -->
<div>
  <p>Display var1: {{var1}}</p>
  <button @click.prevent="doThis('{{ var1 }}') ">Do This</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out what is happening above but I found a way around it. I let var1 display in the html then added a style of `display:none`. I then used javascript to fetch the contents in my vuejs file:

```
<!-- html -->
<div>
  <p id="get_var1" style="display: none;">{{var1}}</p>
  <button @click.prevent="doThis()">Do This</button>
</div>
```

```
// Vue method
method: {
  doThis(){
    let var1 = document.getElementById("get_var1").textContent
    console.log(var1)
  }
}

// Console:
// Value_of_var1
```

Note that the only reason this is ok is that this isn't sensitive or secret information.